# In RowFilter, how To Select the all the Table Columns in C#?

Tags: c#, rowfilter

Here Is My Code...

Here i have one TextBox. When writing some text automatically match the String and 
find all Row..

now ..but
in my code..here Only Filter using "ClientName" i want search that text from 
all the Column..

How to specify the All The Column in the RowFilter 
plz give me solution

```
    private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      dv.RowFilter = "ClientName Like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
      dgClientMaster.DataSource = dv;
    }
```

Comment: I do not see one right way to do it, but you tried to concatenate the query? Something like: "ClientName Like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' AND OtherColumn Like '%" + txtSeach.Text + "%' AND ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dv.Table.Columns)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} Like '%{1}%' OR ", column.ColumnName, txtSearch.Text);
    }

    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 3, 3);
    dv.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
    dgClientMaster.DataSource = dv;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Furqan Safdar's code, I got the below solution working fine for me.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in DGridView_Main.Columns)
{
  sb.AppendFormat("CONVERT({0}, System.String) LIKE '%{1}%' OR ", column.Name, TxtBx_FilterKeywordForGridView.Text);
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 3, 3);
(DGridView_Main.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
```

I hope it helps others as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
dv.RowFilter = "[Column1] + [Column2] + [Column3]" + " Like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the columns you want to search, and separate with an `OR` clause, like this:

```
dv.RowFilter = "ClientName Like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' OR ClientNickName Like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";
```

Also, you'll need to escape single quotes, or you will get a broken query or SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> columns = dataGrid1.Columns.Select(x => "[" + x.Header + "]").ToList();
    string query = String.Format("{0} Like '%{1}%'", String.Join("+", columns), txtSearch.Text);
    dv.RowFilter = query;
}
```